# No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath error printed when start ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

When I start ActiveMQ, the console printed below INFO "No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath". Although my activemq works well, I still wonder what's wrong with it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKVUx.png)

Comment: It's `INFO`. Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: because i search these info on the Internet. and many cases showed that it may be something wrong while 'No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath' message appears.

Comment: It's only a problem if you are *expecting* Spring to be present. If you're just running a standalone ActiveMQ, it's only letting you know that there's no Spring context attached.

Comment: ok. i see. i used a standalone ActiveMQ. BTW, i learn how to use ActiveMQ recently and never used it before. could you share some materials or book list for me for deep learning.